# Python 2 csv.DictWriter() Unicode Encode exception handling

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, export-to-csv, ordereddict

My code below:

```
with open('C:\\Users\\...\\Documents\\RP_test_8.txt', 'w') as f:
    cf = csv.DictWriter(f, column_headers, extrasaction='ignore') 
    cf.writeheader()
    cf.writerows(r.data for r in records)
```

gives me a unicode encode exception:

```
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-141-410d45c40cce> in <module>()
      2     cf = csv.DictWriter(f, column_headers, extrasaction='ignore')
      3     cf.writeheader()
----> 4     cf.writerows(r.data for r in records)

C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\csv.pyc in writerows(self, rowdicts)
    156         for rowdict in rowdicts:
    157             rows.append(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
--> 158         return self.writer.writerows(rows)
    159 
    160 # Guard Sniffer's type checking against builds that exclude complex()

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 30: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You can encode each value in the dictionary as follows and then send the final list of dictionaries to the `writerows` function. You can also encode the key if needed.

```
import csv
cf = csv.DictWriter(f, column_headers, extrasaction='ignore')
cf.writeheader()
final_dict_list = []
for r in records:
    for d in r.data:
        final_dict_list.append({k:v.encode('utf8') for k,v in d.items()})
cf.writerows(final_dict_list)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer; but I get an AttributeError:'unicode' object has no attribute 'items' on the line that starts with final_dict_list.append(). Later, I found a workaround; that is adding import unicodecsv.